# Cakephp 3+ Save array in one filed of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

I'm doing a contacts function to my app and i wanna put a Tags function on it. but I wont create a table only for this, I want to use a field of a row contacts like

```
id | Contact | Name | Tags    
1  | test@...|Test  |["a","b"]
```

and in my contacts.ctp

```
<?php foreach($contacts as $contact){
echo "Name : $contact->name Contact : $contact->contact <br> tags:";
foreach($contact->tags as $tag){
echo $tag; 
}}?>
```

Comment: Saving array to database field directly maynot be possible. But you can try saving it by converting it to a JSON string. All you have to do is just to decode to get back the original array

Answer (score 0):

I don't think saving array makes sense..

you can save a comma separated text by using [Implode func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). like

```
<?php

    $arr = array("test1","test2","test3");
    $str = implode(',',$arr);
    echo $str;
?>
```

*Assumed you have single dimensional array.

Comment: I'm trying to make a Tags function without the Tags table, to save a user tag in their own row.

Comment: @KelvinPrimo, can you please update your question in detailed way.

Comment: ok, i did it. I already did it in javascript. but it cause problems on mobile phones.

Comment: @KelvinPrimo thats great.. :)